# dojox.io is undefined

Tags: dojo

I use dojo mobile for my mobile application. I like to show any contents of another site in my application. for this I will get content from my site. 
I found out that for this I shold use [cross site xhr](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/31/cross-site-xhr-plugin-registry/). But I get error a dojox.io is undefined error!!!

I'm really frustrated. I search the whole day, but without success....
can anyone help me with a small example (with all informations and really domain-name). Which "require" do I needed?

thanks in advance

dimi

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to call the `dojox.io.xhrPlugins.addCrossSiteXhr` function, to get the module name all you need to do is remove the function name:

```
dojo.require('dojox.io.xhrPlugins');
```

The only exception to this rule is when you require a class, since the class name is already the module name.

```
dojo.require('dojit.Tree');
```

---

If nothing still works, you can always fallback to finding the module file by hand, since the module name is correlated with the file path.

Comment: this problem is now resolved. but i have still problem with cross site access!!!
can anyone posts one full and simple example how i can make a cross site connection???

where i must add "Access-Control: allow <*>"?

PLEAAASSSSEEEE

Comment: The Access-Control header has to be provided by the other web server. (The one you want to get your stuff from)

Comment: it is possible to get html-content for example of www.google.com?